# IIS7 Url Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a url:

http://mysite:82/edit.aspx?c=dashboard

I want to rewrite it to:
http://mysite/admin

Bascially, I want the port and query string to be dropped for any incoming url on that site.

Answer (score 0):

routing `/edit.aspx?c=dashboard` to `/admin` can be done with ASP.NET

even though routing can be used for this and is a good method of routing urls like this
(see: [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)) ...

the old rewritepath will work in your case - more info: [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

In Global.asax (in the root of your asp.net app)

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rewriter();
}

private void Rewriter()
{
    Uri url = Context.Request.Url;
    if (url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().EndsWith("/admin"))
    {
        string rewritePath = "edit.aspx?c=dashboard";
        Context.RewritePath(rewritePath);
    }
}
```

for "rewriting" the domain part you'll need to have your website setup in IIS on port 80 in order to drop the port portion (`:82`)

You can do that via the **Bindings...** for the website

[image]

Comment: Changing the port is not an option atm. We have Tomcat running on port 80 and will eventually port this asp.net site to php to run under tomcat. But for now, the rewriting would've been sweet:/